# image permalink PHP problem with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

the site is http://www.christopherwaller.com/wordpress/

if you take a look on the above site i'm trying to insert a link to a page on each of the images on a carousel, so if you click anywhere on the image it will navigate to a new page. I have created the link i want on the post title text (ie. Look 1, Look 2 etc . . .) by using

```
<h2 class="postitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

but i can't for the life of me find the right PHP to create the same links on each of the carousel photos?

I'm still trying to get to grips with PHP if anyone could advise that would be great.thanks

this is the PHP

```
    <div class="edit"><?php edit_post_link(); ?></div>
        </div>

            <div class="postcontent">
            <?php
            $content = $post->post_content;
            $searchimages = '~<img [^>]* />~';              
            preg_match_all( $searchimages, $content, $pics );

            $iNumberOfPics = count($pics[0]);
            if ( $iNumberOfPics > 0 ) { ?>

            <?php the_thumb('medium'); ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="imgframe"></div>
             <?php } ?>










            <div class="post_content">

                <h2 class="postitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages('<p class="pages"><strong>'.__('Pages:').'</strong> ', '</p>', 'number'); ?>
                <div class="post_meta">
                <div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div>
                <div class="date_meta"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
                <div class="category_meta"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        <div class="postbg_bottom"></div>
            <div class="social_links">
            <a class="read" title="Read the rest of this post" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more</a>
              </div>
        </div>
            <?php endwhile ?>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="nxt_page"><?php previous_posts_link('New Entries »', 0); ?></div>
                <div class="prv_page"><?php next_posts_link('« Old Entries', '0') ?></div>
             </div>   
            <?php endif ?>

  </div>
 </div>
 <!--CONTENT END-->
```

and the CSS

```
/* Easy Slider */



 #slider ul, #slider li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}



#slider li, #slider2 li{ width:1000px;height:1100px;} 







#nextBtn{display:block; width:13px; height:14px; position:relative; left:0px; top:0px; z- index:1000; right:120px; top:-718px; float:left; left:840px; margin-right:20px; }



#prevBtn{display:block; width:13px; height:14px; position:relative; left:300px; top:0px; z-index:1000; right:120px; top:-718px; float:left; left:-100px; margin-right:20px; }  



#prevBtn{ left:-20px;}              

#nextBtn a, #prevBtn a{  display:block;position:relative;width:13px;height:14px;

background:url(images/sl_left.png) no-repeat 0 0;} 



#nextBtn a{ background:url(images/sl_right.png) no-repeat 0 0;}



.graphic, #prevBtn, #nextBtn{padding:0; display:block; overflow:hidden; text-indent:-8000px;}





/* Easy Slider END */



/*SLIDER END*/
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really understand what the problem is? What is exactly the code that is not working?

Comment: sorry @AJweb , im trying to insert the same link to the post image on the as is on the post title at present ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following instead of "the_thumb();"

add the following to your theme's 'functions.php'

```
// Add post thumbnail theme support
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

Then use the following to replace the 'the_thumb();'

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
    the_post_thumbnail();
```

I actually use this myself and [created a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nnd-link-post-thumbnails-to-post/) that links the post thumbnail to the post.  It seems like you're trying to do the same kind of thing so I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are using the [PostThumb revisited plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/alakhnors-post-thumb/), correct? And if I read correctly, this plugin outputs a single picture with `the_excerpt()` . If that is the case, couldn't you just do this? :

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</a>
```